# How to create multiple independent Maven Multi Modules in a monorepo?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

How can I create multiple independent Maven Multi Modules in a monorepo?
If I don't have any modules in the parent pom, they are only displayed as folders.
The background is that each individual parent pom should be built and released independently, but managed in a monorepo.

In addition, there is an error from intellij that a pom.xml is missing in the folder repo.
Is this an intellij limitation or a Maven problem with this structure?

These individual parent poms look like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>xyz</groupId>
      <artifactId>repo-parent</artifactId>
      <version>DEV-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <artifactId>module-parent1</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <modules>
      <module>module1</module>
      <module>module2</module>
   </modules>

</project>
```

[image]

After a complete restart it works: No clue what the issue was :)

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use a monorepo for this?